# iOS How to create a secure POST request and open url into browser with autologin

Tags: ios, nsurl

I am new to IOS development.

I am creating an application where i have to open website from ios app.

On app - when user opens the app first time i am telling user to login and i am saving the credentials to keychain so that user don't have to login every time.

As per my client's request i need to create a button link to website. when the link will open ther should be automatically logged in to website.

I know that i can use (BOOL)[UIApplication openURL:(NSURL *)url] to open a url in safari but NSURL does not contain any request data.

Is there any other solution? I don't want to make GET request as it's not a safe option.

Thanks